# JavaScript execution failed connected to mongoHQ shell

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

Trying to access MongoHQ directly:

```
> mongo mongodb://heroku:mypassword@alex.mongohq.com:10046/myapp
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://heroku:mypassword@alex.mongohq.com:10046/myapp
Tue Jun  4 16:10:09.255   Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 211
0x10017116b 0x100135396 0x100068356 0x100129bab 0x10010f92f 0x10024b2fa 0x139ba3a06362 0x139ba3a0ce93 0x139ba3a400c9 0x139ba3a0c76e 
 0   mongo                               0x000000010017116b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongo                               0x0000000100135396 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 310
 2   mongo                               0x0000000100068356 _ZN5mongo16ConnectionString5parseERKSsRSs + 1878
 3   mongo                               0x0000000100129bab _ZN5mongo17mongoConsExternalEPNS_7V8ScopeERKN2v89ArgumentsE + 187
 4   mongo                               0x000000010010f92f _ZN5mongo7V8Scope10v8CallbackERKN2v89ArgumentsE + 175
 5   mongo                               0x000000010024b2fa _ZN2v88internalL30Builtin_HandleApiCallConstructENS0_12_GLOBAL__N_116BuiltinArgumentsILNS0_21BuiltinExtraArgumentsE1EEEPNS0_7IsolateE + 618
 6   ???                                 0x0000139ba3a06362 0x0 + 21559186056034
 7   ???                                 0x0000139ba3a0ce93 0x0 + 21559186083475
 8   ???                                 0x0000139ba3a400c9 0x0 + 21559186292937
 9   ???                                 0x0000139ba3a0c76e 0x0 + 21559186081646
Tue Jun  4 16:10:09.264 JavaScript execution failed: Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:211 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114
exception: connect failed
```

What's to be done?

Comment: Contact mongohq for support (http://support.mongohq.com/getting-started/mongohq.html)

Comment: try different syntax to connect: mongo --host alex.mongohq.com --port 10046 -d myapp --user xxx --password yyy

Comment: the problem doesn't have anything to do with mongohq - it's a mongo shell bug.  The shell doesn't support standard connection strings https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3254

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a shell bug and it's not a new one.  Basically the mongo shell doesn't accept the same format of connection string that regular mongodb drivers do.  I can reproduce this error in the current and previous versions and this syntax isn't expected to work (though it probably shouldn't crash either, but there is already a bug for the shell to accept standard connection string:  jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3254

Meanwhile you can connect by using the mongo shell options such as

```
mongo -u <user> -p <passwd> hostIP:port/db
```

or

```
mongo --host host --port port [ other options ] db
```

Comment: the first line worked for me! (the second one didn't). Thank you!!

Comment: This might be version dependent - the second line should work if you just give the dbname last (without -d)

Comment: For me it did not crash before I switched to Yosemite. But at least, the other variant works :)

Answer (score 0):

Just see if you have $ in your password, in that scenario enclose your password with ' ' then try to connect.

e.g.

> mongo mongodb://host:port/authdb -username
>   dbusername -p 'password$123'