# Writing to a Deployed Meteor's App MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, objcmongodb

I have a meteor app in which I am using a mongoDB [ObjC driver](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB) to write to it from an ios app. This works fine when the meteor app is running locally (port 3000). I simply use `dbConn = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1:3002" error:&error];` The problem is once I deploy the app to meteor.com. I can find the ip address by using `ping whatever.meteor.com` but where do I go from there. I don't know how to write to the deployed mongoDB. It should be fairly simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to change the host IP to reflect the server that is hosting your MongoDB node. It will be something other than 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Also, you should verify if authentication is turned off or on. If on, then you will need credentials (username and password).

Comment: @Rishi I can find the ip address using `ping whatever.meteor.com` in terminal, but it's not still port :3002 is it?

Comment: hard to say, but probably not. Did you try port 27017 (Mongo's default server port).

Comment: @Rishi yeah I did try that port. How do I test if authentication is turned off or on. I do not have the insecure package. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You need to obtain a username, password and the associated db name. Once you have that you can connect using a connection string like: "mongodb://<username>:<password>@whatever.meteor.com:27017/<dbname>"

Comment: @Rishi thanks. I have also looked at [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) which complements what you are saying. Can I test the string to see if it works using the shell?

Comment: Surely, in the shell you can test connection using: `$ mongo whatever.meteor.com:27017/<dbname> -u <username> -p <password>`

Comment: @Rishi using meteor the command it `$ meteor mongo whatever.meteor.com:27017` which allow for the use of looking at collections `db.collection.find()`. However I still can't get the driver to connect, using a similar string.

Comment: You need to find out the username and password. `meteor mongo` probably is handling authentication for you, so it's not helping you do that. Try to connect using the mongo shell, as Rishi suggests.

Comment: ObjCMongoDB doesn't have auth support; see https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/pull/4. I'll try to get that in; meanwhile you could try making ganglio's changes in your copy.

Comment: Sort of an aside: the Mongo wire protocol is unencrypted, so generally I would advise against this particular architecture… I think even the password is sent in the clear.

Comment: @noa great thanks for the response. I will try to get it working. Also good to known about the unencryption. That might become an issue later in development but for right now I'm not too worried about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get temporary mongodb credentials run this command:

```
meteor mongo whatever.meteor.com --url
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009756/219238

Note that the credentials will only be valid for 1 minute so the proper way to save data from your ObjectiveC client is to have it communicate with the meteor webserver instead of directly with mongodb.  The simplest way to do this is to expose a REST endpoint using the `iron-router` package as outlined here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/#server-side-routing

Comment: The command returns `mongodb://client-89674e99:60036738-de64-cde9-ecc1-b58abf778d44@production-db-c3.meteor.io:27017/whatever_meteor_com` which gives me the ability to communicate to the mongoDB for 1 min. Are my collections still called `meteor.collection` or just simply `collection`?

Comment: @Nate, this is controlled by the ObjC driver.  Looking through the wiki, it looks like "mydb.collection": https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/wiki/TheBasics#wiki-setting-up-the-database-connection

Comment: If I was to host my own server with my own mongodb, would the string still need to be refreshed every 1 minute? Or is that feature just a built in .meteor.com security feature?

Comment: @Nate, using an externally hosted mongodb avoids the 1 minute refresh.  Based on Noa's comment, its still not secure to send data directly to mongo though.  So externally hosted or not, you'll still want to have another service in between that can secure the messages.  Once secure galaxy hosting is available you can do it right from your meteor app.   You can actually do it now on meteor.com but I don't think you can use a custom domain and still get ssl in the current setup.

Comment: I do this, but then with using the given url, I get "not authorized for insert on meteor.db.myCollection." Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?