# Clone Mongo DB from Server to localhost in Meteor App [Environment Variable]

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, terminal, meteor

I have a Meteor App running on Modulus.net server. The App is using by many people, So I want to use the same Database Locally. I'm using Ubuntu 12.

I read other `SO` Posts, but none of them found useful.

I tried this code

```
$ export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@mongo.onmodulus.net/dbId?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeoutMS=60000
$ meteor run
```

It throws an Error

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 45. Restarting.
Can't start mongod
MongoDB cannot open or obtain a lock on a file
```

I have also tried `sudo mrt` as I have installed meteorite, now the app is running but the database not changed.

I'm a newbie to Terminal, Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set a port for mongo in the url For example: `mongodb://user:pass@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/...`. On that server, is that port open to the outside world?

Comment: They have given this URL to connect, I have to confirm they support Port or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you replace `user:pass` and `dbId` to your `username`, `password`, and `dbID`?

You can use `mongo mongodb://user:pass@mongo.onmodulus.net/dbId` to check whether you can access it or not first.

### Update

Sorry for the misleading answer, mongo shell has a bug to log in while you enter the url like so. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929040/javascript-execution-failed-connected-to-mongohq-shell)

Your code runs successfully on my computer. You can try to delete `.meteor/local` and then execute `meteor run` again.

If you want to use `sudo` to execute it, add the argument `-E` so that the environment variables will not be reset:

```
sudo -E meteor run
```

Comment: Yes. I changed the Username, password and DB ID